# Why is break-after: page; ignored inside CSS columns?

Tags: css, page-break, css-multicolumn-layout, print-style

Let's say I have this code:

```html
<div class="chapter">
  <div class="subchapter column-span-all">
    <table class="break-after-page">
      ...
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="subchapter">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```css
.chapter {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 4em;
}
.subchapter.column-span-all {
    column-span: all;
}
.subchapter {
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
@media print { 
    break-after-page {
        break-after: page
    }
}
```

When printing now, the table doesn't get a page break after it, the next elements are printed on the same page.
If I however disable the `column-*` properties for `.chapter`, the table gets its own page on printing.

In the real example, I have 10 subchapters and only this one should have a page break afterwards when printing and span both columns. How can I achieve this?

Browser used is Chrome 66.

Answer (score 1):

In your `@media print` CSS rule, you wrote `break-after-page { ... }`

But `break-after-page` is a *class* (for your `table`), so in CSS you need to write it with a leading dot, like `.break-after-page { ... }`